# Which library in .net framework can be used to execute programs?

Tags: c#

I'd like to write a program that would have the following funcionality:
The user execute the program (console application in C#), type the program name, then press the Enter key and the program should initialize.

Comment: I believe windows console do just that.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is built into the core of .NET, no external library required:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Process`*<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)</sup>* class. That should get you started, and if you have any trouble, post another question.

Here's the example from the linked MSDN documentation:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                // You can start any process.
                // HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();

                // This code assumes the process you are starting will 
                // terminate itself.  
                //
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot 
                // terminate it on the desktop, it must terminate itself 
                // or you can do it programmatically from this application 
                // using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this once I'll give you the codes.  If you want to make your launcher more sophisticated, that part is up to you.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = args[0];
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.Start();
    }
}
```